# Dialog position for scroll in IE

Tags: jquery

I tried to center the dialog when scrolling. Here is my code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
   $('.dialog-message').dialog("option", "position", $('.dialog-message').dialog("option", "position")); 
});
```

In Chrome it works well, but in IE(11) dialogue is "twitches" and "blinks". What is the reason?

Comment: create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3nwj17c7/2/